# How do I change div text using array values with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a website and the homepage will basically have 2 div's containing text. I want one of the divs to change every 2 seconds with values I've placed in an array

```
var skills = ["text1","text2","text3","text4"];
var counter = 0;
var previousSkill = document.getElementById("myGreetingSkills");
var arraylength = skills.length - 1;

function display_skills() {
    if(counter === arraylength){
        counter = 0;
    }
    else {
        counter++;  
    }
}
previousSkill.innerHTML = skills[counter];
setTimeout(display_skills, 2000);
```

Comment: Put this line **previousSkill.innerHTML = skills[counter];** in function

Comment: ... and another `setTimeout` too, or use `setInterval` instead, otherwise the function is executed only once.

Comment: yes, #anwerjunaid is right, otherwise `skills[counter]` will always display `text1` as it's outside the function scope.

Comment: innerHTML is evil: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395051/if-innerhtml-is-evil-then-whats-a-better-way-change-the-text-of-a-link

Comment: @Alex The post you've linked doesn't seem to support your disclaimer ...? Answers are introducing alternatives, and even defending `innerHTML` ("innerHTML is not evil at all"), but I can't find any proofs `innerHTML` being evil.

Comment: @Teemu yes.. it does?!

Comment: @Teemu THANK YOU SO MUCH! OMG I feel soooo stupid -_- setInterval works better for repeating functions. Again Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap `display_skills` inside a function in your `setTimeout()` and use `setInterval()` instead.

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function(){display_skills()}, 2000);
```

And make sure you call `previousSkill.innerHTML = skills[counter];` *inside* your interval'd function - else it will run just once.

You can terminate your interval with `window.clearInterval(myInterval);`

Answer (score 2):

`innerHTML` is evil, use jQuery! (assuming because you have it selected as a tag)

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6uytz209/)

```
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    var skills = ["text1","text2","text3","text4"],
      counter = skills.length - 1,
      previousSkill = $("#myGreetingSkills"),
      arraylength = skills.length - 1;

    function display_skills() {
      if (counter === arraylength) {
          counter = 0;
      }
      else {
          counter++;  
      }
      previousSkill.html(skills[counter]);
    }

    display_skills();

    setInterval(function() {
      display_skills();
    }, 2000);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Just a nit-pick: jQuery uses `innerHTML` [under the hood](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.fn.html), though they are using it correctly ; ).

Answer (score -1):

Use `array.join()`.
The syntax of this function is array.join(string), where3 string is the joining character.
Example:
`[1, 2, 3].join(" & ")` will return `"1 & 2 & 3"`.

Hope this helps,

Awesomeness01